# jupyterhub: Ubuntu 20.04 - port 80 blocked when accessed remotely

Tags: networking, ubuntu, firewall, jupyter

I started a web service running on port :80. The service is available from localhost, but from remote IP addresses seems to be blocked. Ping from remote IPs is OK, firewall seems to be inactive.

**What could be blocking the service?**

**Details:**

**Started Jupyterhub service**

```
> sudo jupyterhub --port 80
```

**Web browser from localhost** (commandline from localhost)

The service is accessible from from localhost

```
lynx $ lynx http://127.0.0.1:80/hub/
```

or with absolute address (from localhost)

```
lynx $ lynx http://123.123.123.123/
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

As well ping from remote IPs is successful:

```
c:\Users>ping 123.123.123.123
Pinging 123.123.123.123 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 123.123.123.123: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=54
Reply from 123.123.123.123: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=54
```

**Problem**
When accessed from other IP adresses the service seems to be unavailable

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

**Firewall status:**

```
:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Tried also to enable ufw (no success):

```
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw enable
sudo service ufw start
```

Open ports:

```
ss -lntu | grep ':80'
tcp    LISTEN  0        511                                    127.0.0.1:8001                           0.0.0.0:*                                            
tcp    LISTEN  0        128                                    127.0.0.1:8080                           0.0.0.0:*                                            
tcp    LISTEN  0        511                                            *:80                                   *:*
```

Comment: your first line references port 8080 and your second port 80. when you say "when accessed from other IP addresses" what port are you referencing to? could you edit your post with the output of `netstat -anutp | grep ":80" from the server?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried both 8080 and 80 ports. None (8080 or 80) of them was working, unfortunately (corrected in the original question).

Comment: your comment is a bit confusing, but from your output we can read that port 8080 listens ONLY on localhost (thus not available outside of the host) and port 80 listens on all interfaces. so what is outside for you? is this Ubuntu a VM? if so where is it running? hyper-v? virtualbox?... I see you tried to ping from Windows. is 123.123.123.123 your real IP you are using or just replaced? as this IP is a China Public IP. if it is a VM in your LAN you should use a non-public IP (except you bought one) could you give more background about your network setup.

Comment: It is a standalone server machine. All three listening ports were created after "sudo jupyterhub --port 80" command. IP address was replaced - I am connetced via SSH and ping works.

Comment: what if you start it with an IP setting? per [juputerhub - netowrk basics](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started/networking-basics.html) is is encouraged to set an IP or use `0.0.0.0` instead of `*`, is anything listening on 80 when the jupiterhub is not started?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not in jupzterhub but in iptables, that I did not realised the can be in use.

```
username@tesla:~/paperai$ sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
12189   46M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  !lo    any     anywhere             localhost/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
 299K  716M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   16   960 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     123.123.0.0/16       anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
 2746  168K ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
  169  8488 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:http
  366 18704 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:https
1146K   94M REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```